# Text can not be appended to the file

Tags: c++

I want to append text to the file "filename.txt" but the text won't append. I have even set the attribute **ios_base::app** but it does not work(I have tried deleting the file and starting the program again so that the part where the attribute is added will be run;

```
ifstream MyReadFile("filename.txt");

ifstream f("filename.txt");

bool exits_and_can_be_opened = f.good();

if (exits_and_can_be_opened) {
    cout << "This file already exists";
}
else {
    
    MyWriteFile.open("filename.txt", ios_base::app);

    MyWriteFile << "Files can be tricky, but it is fun enough!";

    MyWriteFile.close();

}



while (getline(MyReadFile, myText)) {
    // Output the text from the file
    cout << myText << "\n";
}

MyWriteFile << "This thing was appended";


cout << "This was the final change";
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There are no errors, it just does not work, and the else statement works as the file is being created

Comment: What is `MyWriteFile`? How is it related to `MyReadFile`? Why are you trying to open the same file three times?

Comment: MyReadFile is not related to my issue. I am sorry for this inconvenience, I will remove that from the question.(But if you are interested then it just reads the file which is being created)

Comment: `MyWriteFile << "This thing was appended";` why are you doing output operation on the input stream?

Comment: I will change that to fstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open the file for reading and writing, and then use positioning functions to move around in the file or to switch from reading to writing

```
fstream MyFile("filename.txt");

while (getline(MyFile, myText)) {
    // Output the text from the file
    cout << myText << "\n";
}

MyFile.clear();                       // clear any error
MyFile.seekg(0, ios_base::end);       // move to the end of the file
MyFile << "This thing was appended";
```

The other (maybe simpler) way is to close and reopen the file every time you want to switch from reading to writing. Don't have the same file opened twice simultaneously.

Comment: It works when the file was created before but does not work when the file was created and then this action took place

Comment: @BahramGozalov I'm not sure I understand. What's the difference between 'was created before` and 'was created'?

Comment: @BahramGozalov I expect that you are ignoring my advice **Don't have the same file opened twice simultaneously**, it's very important

Comment: When I told was created before I have meant it was existent before, and was created means was created when the code was run(I know that the point which I was trying to reach was vague, my bad).  And I would like to point out that u have meant that opening one file twice is not the best practice( I took it as an advice not as a mandatory thing but now I understand). Thanks for your help, attention and time! Now everything works(I have just appended the text in the code part itself as I understood that opening the file twice isn't the best thing to do.

Comment: @BahramGozalov Glad it's working. Actually, just to add a bit more information. it is OK to have a file opened multiple times as long as it's for reading **only**. It's when you try to mix reading and writing that you get problems.